Taking a supremum over positive elements in the center of a von Neumann algebra
Let $(M,\tau)$ be a finite tracial von Neumann algebra with center $Z$ and standardly represented on $L^{2}(M)$. Let $z_{0}\in Z^{+}$. I want to show that $\|z_{0}\|_{\infty}^{2}=\text{sup}\{\tau(z_{0}z):z\in Z^{+}, \tau(z)\leq1\}$.

(This pertains to an older version of the OP’s question.)
I presume you meant the supremum of $|\tau(z_0 z^{\frac{1}{2}})|$, or alternatively $z_0 \in Z^+$. Otherwise $\tau(z_0 z^{\frac{1}{2}})$ can easily be complex and the supremum doesn’t even make sense.
Regardless, the claim is false even after those alterations. Let $M = Z = L^\infty([0, 1])$ and the trace be given by the Lebesgue measure. Let $z_0 = x$, the identity function from $[0, 1]$ to itself. We observe that, for any $0 \leq a \leq 1$, and $z \in Z^+$ with $\tau(z) = 1$,
$$\begin{split}
\tau(z_0 z^{\frac{1}{2}}) &= \tau(z_0 1_{[0, a]} z^{\frac{1}{2}}) + \tau(z_0 1_{(a, 1]} z^{\frac{1}{2}})\\
&\leq \tau(a 1_{[0, a]} z^{\frac{1}{2}}) + \tau(1_{(a, 1]} z^{\frac{1}{2}})\\
&\leq a \cdot a^{\frac{1}{2}} \tau(z)^{\frac{1}{2}} + (1-a)^{\frac{1}{2}}\tau(z)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= a^{\frac{3}{2}} + (1-a)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{split}$$
Where the second inequality used Cauchy-Schwarz. Plugging in $a = 0.1$, say, we see the RHS can be strictly smaller than $1$. Since the RHS does not depend on $z$, we see the supremum in question is strictly smaller than $1$, but $\|z_0\|_\infty = 1$, so the claimed equality is false.

(The following pertains to the current version of the OP’s question.)
The corrected statement, as I noted, should be for $z_0 \in Z^+$, we have $\|z_0\|_\infty = \sup\{\tau(z_0 z): z \in Z^+, \tau(z) \leq 1\}$. This can be proved as follows:
Recall that operator norms do not depend on the choice of faithful representation. Thus, we may simply consider $Z$ represented on $L^2(Z, \tau)$. Observe that $Z \subset L^2(Z, \tau)$ is dense, from which it easily follows that $\{x \in Z: \|x\|_{2, \tau} \leq 1\} \subset \{h \in L^2(Z, \tau): \|h\|_2 \leq 1\}$ is dense. Now, as $z_0$ is a positive operator, we have,
$$\begin{split}
\|z_0\|_\infty &= \sup_{h \in L^2(Z, \tau), \|h\|_2 \leq 1} \langle h, z_0h\rangle\\
&= \sup_{x \in Z, \|x\|_{2, \tau} \leq 1} \langle x, z_0x\rangle\\
&= \sup_{x \in Z, \tau(x^\ast x) \leq 1} \tau(x^\ast z_0x)\\
&= \sup_{x \in Z, \tau(xx^\ast) \leq 1} \tau(z_0xx^\ast)\\
&= \sup_{z \in Z^+, \tau(z) \leq 1} \tau(z_0z)
\end{split}$$

The correct equality should have been $|z_0|_\infty$ equals the supremum of $|\tau(z_0 z)|$ (instead of $|\tau(z_0 z^{\frac{1}{2}})|$ over all $z \in Z^+$ and $\tau(z) = 1$.

Thanks. I updated the question. It should be squared, right?

@SihOASHoihd It’s still not right. If you multiply $z_0$ by some $C > 0$, the RHS gets multiplied by $C$ but the LHS gets multiplied by $C^2$, so the equality cannot be correct. The correct statement is simply that your RHS equals $|z_0|_\infty$, without squaring.

Can you share the proof if you know it?

@SihOASHoihd I’ve edited my answer to add the proof.

Let me also point out that this is a quite standard fact in the theory of tracial vNa’s. By the same proof, this result is true not just for the center $Z$, but for any tracial vNa $M$. In the commutative case, as the vNa reduces to $L^\infty$ of some probability space, this is nothing more than saying $L^\infty$ has $L^1$ as its predual.

Thank you. I was working along these lines, but for some reason I was getting tripped up.
